# readthedocs autobuild needs Fortran compiler: Upload locally built files instead?

Tags: python, packaging, read-the-docs

I have a package for which the documentation is produced automatically using Sphinx and readthedocs.

When I `make html` locally it works fine, the local version of the html files can be navigated etc.

When I push to git the autobuild of these docs is triggered but fails, as it cannot import the package. I have a readthedocs.yml file that requests the package be built in an environment using `python setup.py install` and installs the dependencies from requirements.txt.

Unfortunately my python package includes fortran, and there is no fortran compiler in the environment set up by readthedocs (and as far as I am aware no intention of including one)

What I would like to know is, is there a way of forcing readthedocs to just use the locally built html files by uploading them to git, and avoid the autobuild process?